# Conditional statement for mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 sql table like this :

[image]

Table 1 and 2 is data input, and the result in table 3. The problem is not in total and nilai, but in coloumn saran. how to show the result for coloumn saran with conditional statement like this :total >= nilai then saran refers to Mayor and minor from table 1. if total < nilai then saran refers to butuh in table 2?

thanks

Comment: Can you show the desired output, my friend?

Comment: so whats the question here?

Comment: In google spreadshet in these link in table 3 is my desire, sory i can't post picture or table.

Comment: so you want to combine your results from two tables into a new table? (tbl 3)

Comment: I dont see any common ground between the first and second table... we need more data

Comment: 1st and 2nd tables does not allow to produce 3rd table, resolution: it is impossible

Comment: We would be delightful to help you if you show the columns of input tables and how you join them.

Comment: does table 1 have a BIDANG? it looks like you have a BIDANG X for NIP 1,2... BIDANG Y for NIP 3... BIDANG Z for NIP 4,5

Comment: ok.. i have been for edited my question. thanks

Comment: so where are you getting total? from what table? and where are you getting NILAI?

Comment: Nilai from difrence betwen max and min from coloumn total with the same value in coloumn bidang

Answer (score 1):

Ok,.... so dealing with the little information we had, I put together a working example of what you want. I added TOTAL and NILAI to Table1 because I didn't know where you were storing that. so you will have to make the appropriate changes, but this should do the trick.

```
SELECT 
  m1.NIP,
  m1.BIDANG,
  m1.TOTAL,
  m1.NILAI,
  IF(m1.TOTAL <= m1.NILAI, m2.BUTUH, CONCAT(m1.MAYOR, ',', m1.MINOR)) as SARAN 
FROM myTab1 m1
JOIN myTab2 m2 on m1.BIDANG = m2.BIDANG
```

SEE WORKING EXAMPLE: --  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6cb2/10

---

basically what you want to do is use that IF() statement in the select. Its saying IF (condition, true, false) so IF(TOTAL <= NILAI then put in m2.BUTUH else put in CONCAT(the two columns MAYOR and MINOR with a comma inbetween)....

---

you had a discrepancy with your question though. you said if total >= NILAI then do table1 MAYOR AND MINOR or if its less than NILAI then to table2 BUTUH... problem is the output you had was for TOTAL > NILAI then do MAYOR and MINOR.... not >=. So i'm not sure which one you want there either, may need to change. I just went with the outputted data